# How can I get my Wacom tablet to use the mouse in relative (touchpad) mode?

Tags: mouse, wacom, bamboo

I am currently using Ubuntu 11.10 with a first edition Wacom Bamboo Fun 4x6 tablet. The Wacom tablet driver in Ubuntu acknowledges the Wacom pen and its buttons just fine.

However, it doesn't switch to relative mode when I use the Wacom mouse. Also, switching to relative mode manually using the applet in System Settings will not work with the mouse.  It stays in absolute or tablet mode.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The solution I applied was:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" Mode "Relative"
```

`Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus` is the device which can be listed by the command: `xsetwacom --list devices`

Answer (score 0):

Information provided [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Xsetwacom), can be useful for you in order to properly configure your tablet using the xsetwacom utility.

Pay special attention to this part, which defines the tablet mode:

> ## Mode
>
> The Mode parameter sets the device mode as either Relative, the default for cursor (the Wacom tablet mouse) and tablet touch or
>   Absolute, the default for the stylus, eraser, and tablet PC touch.
>   Relative Mode means pointer tracking for the device will function like
>   a mouse, whereas Absolute Mode means the pointer corresponds to the
>   device's actual position on the tablet or tablet PC screen. An example
>   of the command would be:  xsetwacom set "device name" Mode "Absolute"
>
> Note that using the Mode parameter in an xsetwacom command will
>   prevent you from pulling a Guideline in Gimp with your mouse due to a
>   long standing GTK bug.

There is a way to make this behavior the default and make it permanent. All the information is provided in the appropriate section.

Good luck!

Comment: In typical WWW fashion, the reference link has died. Please supply in the answer how to make it permanent? For xorg apparently you need to either append set commands to `~/.xinitrc` or change `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf` -- not at all obvious from the manpage.